# Prototype serialize only visible form field value

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, visible

Is it possible in `prototype.js` to serialize only the visible form field values. I have a form in which to elements have the same name but one is visible but another is hidden. When I am serializing the form using `$('formid').serialize()`, then the both fields value are coming and output is like:

```
user_email=abc@example.com&mymodule_custom_delivery_area=20&mymodule_custom_delivery_area=test
```

The first element was a drop down when second was a text box. The text box was hidden and drop down was shown. Both have the same name. I do not want to take the hidden text box value. How can I do this? Thanks

Comment: Just don't set it to `hidden`, but remove it entirely?

Answer (score 3):

**Warning**: Incomplete solution; feel free to use it as a starting point for a better solution:

Unfortunately I have not found a good way to do this in the general case, but the following solution works for me, *if* the input element is directly hidden; however it does not work if some input is contained into another element that in turn is hidden.

Anyway, my solution looks like:

```
function check() {
    var inputs = $("myform").getElements();
    var visibleInputs = inputs.grep({ match: function(elem) { return elem.visible();} });
    var serialized = Form.serializeElements(visibleInputs);
    console.log(serialized); // here do something useful with it instead
}
```

On the first line it collects a list all fields fo the form. On the second line it filters all visible elements from that (`grep` needs an item with a `match` function, so I provided a simple dictionary with a `match` key to fool it into thinking I pass in a matcher). Finally only the filtered elements are serialized.

Please: can anyone improve this to exclude input fields which are not visible because some containing element is hidden? I can only think of some brainboggeling complicated `match` function that ascends up all parents and check each one separately if it is hidden.